# Dell PowerEdge 2950 with PERC 5/i - pxe-e53 boot

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge, pxe-boot, dell-perc

I have an old PE 2950 that I use for all my home automation needs.
Work great since a while, but, I was trying to upgrade my harddrive and now I have problem.

Here's my setup before :

1- RAID-5 array with 6 disks and 1 Virtual Disks
2- RAID-0 array with 1 disk

My goal was to replace 2 disks in my first array, so I replaced the harddrives then boot the server. I got some config errors before going in the PERC controller management.

From the management, I :
1- Removed all my RAID-5 configuration
2- Created a new disk group in RAID-10 with all my 6 disks
3- Initialized the VD

After that, I saw in the foreign configuration that I had the disk, from my array 2, that was in a "foreign" mode. I then choose to CLEAR all foreign.

I then, after, recreated a disk group and a new VD for my harddisk that I want to be in RAID-0.
Note : I didn't re-initialize it, because I would prefer to not lost the DATA originally on the disk.

So now my config is :
1- RAID-10 array with 6 disks and 1 Virtual Disks
2- RAID-0 array with 1 disk

I as able to reboot the server and boot on a DVD to install ESXI-5. From the installation, I was able to see my 2 virtual disks so I decided to install the OS on my VD from my  RAID-10 configuration.
Install has been successul.

But now, after the reboot, I get each time : PXE-E53 No boot.
I am stuck there.

Answer (score 4):

**PXE-E53 No boot error** means your server is trying to boot over the network using the PXE protocol. Most probably you have DHCP server running in your network thus server is getting an IP address and would like to boot but doesn't receive any boot files since I assume you don't have any PXE servers up and running currently.

Check BIOS boot order and settings. Probably you have to add your VD-1 as the first device for boot order and you will be good.

Comment: Thanks sir. While waiting an answer I've just discovered the boot device setting in the controller configuration. It was set to VD-0 which is the VD of my RAID-0 disk. I changed it to VD-1, now I am just waiting the end of another initializing that I started just in case.